# After using TightVNC, cannot copy/paste between Windows applications

Tags: copy, paste, vnc

This is very similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/how-can-i-copy-paste-data-to-and-from-the-windows-clipboard-to-an-opensuse-clipb), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1081489/how-to-enable-text-copy-and-paste-for-vnc), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229595/how-to-fix-broken-paste-clipboard-in-vnc-on-windows) question asked here on SO and elsewhere. But differs significantly. I have tried used these commands on the machine running VNC

```
vncserver :22 -geometry 1600x1200
vncconfig display :22 -nowin &
```

I also tried these commands

```
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
autocutsel -fork
```

The experience I have experienced is different, as follows.

- Before running the VNC Viewer, I can copy/paste between Windows apps
- I start the VNC Viewer, and open a command prompt terminal
- I can copy/paste between Windows apps, between Linux terminals, and
  from Windows apps to a Linux terminal.
- I can copy/paste from a Linux terminal to Windows app, by
  double-clicking on the Linux content and using ctrl-v in Windows.
  However, when I do this, I can no longer copy/paste between Windows
  apps, and from Windows to Linux. That is, the content of the Windows
  clipboard retains the Linux content, and can never be updated using
  ctrl-c. In this case, ctrl-v always pastes the Linux content. To fix
  this, I have to kill the VNC Window and kill the vncserver session.

Anyone else seen this?

Thanks for reading,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

It seems that TightVNC is the culprit here. When I use TigerVNC the issue disppears, and I can copy/paste between Windows apps, and from TightVnc into Windows.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: As I described in my solution, I stopped uisng TightVnc.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VNC Server fixed issue for me:
vncserver -kill :1
from terminal:
vncserver -geometry 1900x1000 -DisconnectClients=0